# h2o.saveModel throwing exception with directory on Windows 8

Tags: r, h2o

I'm using h2o version 3.0.0.22 in R and I'm trying to save my model. But I can't seem to figure out what format is expected. I've tried all sorts of variations but getting all sorts of different exceptions.

> h2o.saveModel(model, dir="c:/temp", name= "my.model")

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/Models.bin/DeepLearningModel__8412f3abf1699b5593a55c6861c8468d?dir=c%3A%2Ftemp%2Fmy.model&force=0)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.persist.PersistManager.getPersistForURI(PersistManager.java:407)"          
 [2] "water.serial.ObjectTreeBinarySerializer.save(ObjectTreeBinarySerializer.java:57)"
 [3] "water.api.ModelsHandler.exportModel(ModelsHandler.java:206)"                     
 [4] "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)"                     
 [5] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                 
 [6] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                 
 [7] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:56)"                                       
 [8] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:677)"                          
 [9] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:614)"                           
[10] "water.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.run(NanoHTTPD.java:438)"                             
[11] "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                                            

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,  : 
  Cannot find persist manager for scheme c
```

How can I save my model on my Windows 8 machine?

UPDATE:
This command here seems to create a folder & file:

> h2o.saveModel(model, filename="file:///C:/temp/model")

This created a file: `C:/temp/DeepLearningModel__8412f3ab21699b5593aa5c6861c8468d.bin`
But then throws a different error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/Models.bin/DeepLearningModel__8412f3abf1699b5593a55c6861c8468d?dir=file%3A%2F%2F%2FC%3A%2Ftemp%2Fmodel&force=0)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)"                                             
 [2] "water.serial.ObjectTreeBinarySerializer.save(ObjectTreeBinarySerializer.java:70)"
 [3] "water.api.ModelsHandler.exportModel(ModelsHandler.java:206)"                     
 [4] "sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)"                     
 [5] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"                 
 [6] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                                 
 [7] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:56)"                                       
 [8] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:677)"                          
 [9] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:614)"                           
[10] "water.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.run(NanoHTTPD.java:438)"                             
[11] "java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"                                            

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,  : 
  Malformed escape pair at index 165: file:///C:/temp/model/modelmetrics_DeepLearningModel__8412f3abf1699b5593a55c6861c8468d@-1218026610891888320_on_TrainingData.hex_1_part0.temporary.sample.9.91%@1615017098181529186.bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2O JIRA contains issue [PUBDEV-1566](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-1566) which is referencing your problem.

You can try to use the latest H2O - 3.0.0.26 which contains fix for the issue. You can find it [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-shannon/26/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. that worked using this syntax `h2o.saveModel(model, filename="file:///C:/temp/model")`