# R: h2o: saving a deeplearning model: automatically generated long file name too long for windows

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I have no problems saving a h20 glm model(as this has a shorter file name) but I am having problems saving a h2o deeplearning model using the exactly the same saving procedure

I tried:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()
a <- runif(1000)
b <- runif(1000)
c <- runif(1000)
d <- 5*a+2*b^2+c*a

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)


df1.hex <- as.h2o(df1)
test.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:3, y = 4, training_frame = df1.hex)


dlmodel.path = h2o.saveModel(test.dl, dir = "file:///C:/", name = "modeldl")
dlmodel.path
```

But get an error:

```
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,  : 
  FS IO Failure: 
 accessed path : file:///C://modeldl/modelmetrics_DeepLearningModel__9fe11910a85d1371379ac7d536d64359_-5064771152374762981_on_Key_Frame__C__Users_store_AppData_Local_Temp_RtmpGGylNe_file1f18787f2989_csv_1.hex_2.DeepLearningModel__9fe11910a85d1371379ac7d536d64359.temporary.train.chunks8_-6759658083019717917.bin
```

I am using a windows 10 computer. As has been pointed out by RHA, the filepath/name is extremely long and is too long for windows.How can I overcome this? Most of the filepath characters are generated automatically by the h20 program.  I am using the latest h20 update.
from.sessionInfo(): other attached packages: [1] h2o_3.0.0.30

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: That filepath/name is extremely long. Could it be too long for windows? I know mac has a 256 limit.

Comment: How can I overcome this? Most of the filepath characters are generated automatically by the h20 program.

Comment: I found out the file name IS really too long for windows, it won't move, delete or rename it. But i don't know how you can change this name. You can make the name of you model shorter (m), but i'm not sure if that is enough.

Comment: Could you try `colnames(test.dl) <- iconv(colnames(test.dl), to='ASCII', sub='')` before saving the model?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: And are you using the last update of H2o? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196199/h2o-savemodel-throwing-exception-with-directory-on-windows-8)

Comment: I am using the latest update.

Comment: from.sessionInfo(): other attached packages:
[1] h2o_3.0.0.30

Comment: Hmm, I ran out of suggestions, sorry. This might well be a bug. I suggest you add the long file issue to the title and add to your questions that you have seen these other questions and that they didn't help. Maybe that will get attention from someone else. (Or, add a bounty.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add model_id = "something" to your h2o.deeplearning command?

```
test.dl <- h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:3, y = 4, training_frame = df1.hex, model_id = "myTest.dl")
```

I hope it could fix your problem.