# Error saving an h2o model in R with h2o.saveModel

Tags: r, h2o

I'm trying to save an h2o model in R with the next code:

```
h2o.saveModel(myModel, path = "myPath/models")
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Models.bin/DeepLearning_model_R_1449814346828_5?dir=D%3A%2FGoogle%20Drive%2FMio%2FKaggle%2FDigital%20Challenge%2Fmodels%2FDeepLearning_model_R_1449814346828_5&force=FALSE)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.api.ModelsHandler.getFromDKV(ModelsHandler.java:126)"                           
 [2] "water.api.ModelsHandler.exportModel(ModelsHandler.java:222)"                          
 [3] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                          
 [4] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"        
 [5] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [6] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)"                                     
 [7] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:64)"                                            
 [8] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:644)"                               
 [9] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:585)"                                
[10] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:617)"                    
[11] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGet(JettyHTTPD.java:559)"                        
[12] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)"                         
[13] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                         
[14] "org.eclipse

.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"               

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  Object 'DeepLearning_model_R_1449814346828_5' not found for argument: model_id
```

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31196199/h2o-savemodel-throwing-exception-with-directory-on-windows-8) but it didn't solve my problem.

Is anyone able to save an h2o model in R? If not I will lose the model when I'll close the session.

Comment: That is the correct way to use `h2o.saveModel`.  Your error looks like the model that you are trying to save is no longer found, did you shut down or lose the connection to your H2O cluster or delete that model before trying to save it?

Comment: No, the cluster was still on. This time, I managed to save the model through the interface, going to http://localhost:54321. But it would be nice to know why it prompted the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, sometimes it happens that it is not able to recognise the model ID, so if you do force=TRUE, it will work. I was also facing the same error and it worked for me.

`model_path <- h2o.saveModel(myModel, path = "myPath/models", force=TRUE)`

The link for official H2o site is below:-
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html